# only piping updated data down a socket using node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am getting data from a url, I'm then sending this data in a socket to push the data to the client.  I've currently got the code to send the data every 10 seconds using setTimeout.  How can I imrprove my code so that I'm only sending the data if it changes.  Currently the data might only change every 30 seconds so I'm sending the same data down the socket for around 30 secs.

I'm using node.js and socket.io.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

The function that is being called every 10 secs:

```
function sendData(socket){
    var thisRef = this;

    //The url we want is "myserver:8000/"
    var options = 
    {
      host: 'myserver',
      path: '/getdata?param1=1&param2=1738517',
      //since we are listening on a custom port, we need to specify it by hand
      port: '8000',
      //This is what changes the request to a GET request
      method: 'GET'
    };

    callback = function(response) 
    {
      var str = ''
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', function () {
        console.log(str);
        socket.emit('timeUpdate', { currentTime: str });
      });


    }
        var req = http.request(options, callback);
        //This is the data we are posting, it needs to be a string or a buffer
        req.write("Hello World!");
        req.end();


    setTimeout(function()
    {


        sendData.call(thisRef,socket)
    },10000);
}
```

Comment: since you are messing with http requests try looking for the http codes , if it hasn't changed it will return `Not-Modified` (302 i think) if its different than that the it has modified and you could emit to clients. not quiet sure if you can achieve this .. but its a point of view

Comment: If you aren't getting 302s, why not cache the previous response and compare it to the new response.